# Windows 8 taking 4+ mins to shutdown

Tags: windows-7, windows, shutdown, windows-8

I did a fresh installation of Windows 8 64 bit, build 9200 (released on aug 16th). I installed the drivers and some basic softwares like NetBeans, mingw, iis server and php. For the first few times, it was restarting normally. But then at shutdown, it would show the shutdown screen for some seconds and then turn black for about 4 mins (similar to what happens at hibernation). 
I disabled the "fast startup" option in power options, but the problem still persists. Windows 7 and Ubuntu shut down normally.
specs:
4gb ram, 
750 gb sata hdd,

**solved** by installing Windows Updates released during October. It was a serious bug in the OS, afaik. Now even hibernate takes upto 30 secs max. Still, win 8 is too buggy for release.

Comment: I would reinstall the operating system, there is clearly some service, that is causing a conflict.

Comment: Go to command prompt, type msconfig, and disable everything under the 'startup' tab you don't need, and then run CCleaner. Try that and see if it changes anything.

Comment: forgot to mention, i also tried disabling all startup items from task manager. btw, this problem isnt related to any pogram running. i get a black screen AFTER the shutdown/restart screen for 3-4 mins. its exactly like hibernate. the problem is related to win 8 hybrid startup

Comment: ** But those updates messed up my USB 2.0 ports and my keyboard. Keyboard randomly stops working and USB 2.0 has stopped working permanently. Reinstalling ASUS chipset drivers on my laptop has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Use xpbootmgr/WPT from the Windows 8 SDK to trace the slow shutdown:

http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/158252-trace-why-windows-8-boots-shutsdown-or-hibernate-slowly/

Answer (score 0):

try to use "shutdown.exe /s /t 0" from command line.
In some cases, using this method, shutdown sequence can be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the Internet and apply Windows updates.